# How do I compress files using powershell that are over 2 GB?

Tags: powershell, zip, system.io.compression, compress-archive, system.io.compression.zipfile

I am working on a project to compress files that range anywhere from a couple mb to several gb's big and I am trying to use powershell to compress them into a .zip. The main problem I am having is that using Compress-Archive has a 2 Gb cap to individual file size, and I was wondering if there was another method to compress files.

Edit:

So for this project we are looking to implement a system to take .pst files from outlook and compress them to a .zip and upload them to a server. Once they are uploaded they will be pulled down from a new device and extracted into a .pst file again.

Comment: @anothervictimofthemouse I have been trying to use that but due to the cap of 2Gb per file I keep running into an error because the file is too big

Comment: Use .NET API directly

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon do you have any articles or resources I could look at to implement this?

Comment: I'll post an answer later if nobody does, you will need to use a file stream for this. Please add more details to your question such as file folder structure you're looking to compress

Comment: You cant use Powershell alone. You either need C# code (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression) or install an external program and let that do the compression (the latter being a lot easier). You could invoke 7Zip from powershell with `Start-Process -FilePath "C:\path\to\7z.exe" -ArgumentList @("a", "c:\path\to\output.zip", "c:\path\to\inputfolder")`. (www.7-zip.org - you must install 7za.exe). Chocolatey(chocolatey.org) can be used to install 7zip from PowerShell

Comment: @MisterSmith that's absolutely wrong. PowerShell can do anything C# can, because they're both based on .NET. You can call Win32 APIs and .NET framework APIs directly from PowerShell

Comment: [powershell compress-archive File size issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32103732/995714)

Comment: @td1126 is it a must to use zip? If not then just use 7z or rar which is much better, or just use the [built-in `tar` command](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/) which can give you bz2 or gz which are also much better than zip. Alternatively compress to \*.wim

Comment: Similar but with no alternative solutions provided: [Compress-Archive command returns "Exception: Stream was too long."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39577931/150605), [Compress-Archive is throwing 'System.OutOfMemoryException'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55177356/150605)

Answer (score 8):

**NOTE**

Further updates to this function will be published to the official [GitHub repo](https://github.com/santisq/PSCompression) as well as to the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSCompression/). The code in this answer **will no longer be maintained**.

Contributions are more than welcome, if you wish to contribute, fork the repo and submit a pull request with the changes.

---

To explain the limitation named on **PowerShell Docs for [`Compress-Archive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-7.2)**:

> The `Compress-Archive` cmdlet uses the Microsoft .NET API [`System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=net-6.0) to compress files. The maximum file size is 2 GB because there's a limitation of the underlying API.

This happens because, *presumably (since 5.1 version is closed source)*, this cmdlet uses a [Memory Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.-ctor?view=net-6.0) to **hold all zip archive entries in memory** before writing the zip archive to a file. Inspecting the [InnerException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.innerexception?view=net-6.0) produced by the cmdlet we can see:

```
System.IO.IOException: Stream was too long.
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object , Int32 , Object )
```

We would also see a similar issue if we attempt to read all bytes from a **file larger than 2Gb**:

```
Exception calling "ReadAllBytes" with "1" argument(s): "The file is too long.
This operation is currently limited to supporting files less than 2 gigabytes in size."
```

Coincidentally, we see the same limitation with [`System.Array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=net-6.0#remarks):

> .NET Framework only: By default, the maximum size of an Array is 2 gigabytes (GB).

---

There is also another limitation pointed out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74129754/15339544), `Compress-Archive` can't compress if another process has a handle on a file.

##### How to reproduce?

```bash
# cd to a temporary folder and
# start a Job which will write to a file
$job = Start-Job {
    0..1000 | ForEach-Object {
        "Iteration ${_}:" + ('A' * 1kb)
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
    } | Set-Content .\temp\test.txt
}

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
# attempt to compress
Compress-Archive .\temp\test.txt -DestinationPath test.zip
# Exception:
# The process cannot access the file '..\test.txt' because it is being used by another process.
$job | Stop-Job -PassThru | Remove-Job
Remove-Item .\temp -Recurse
```

To overcome this issue, and also to emulate explorer's behavior when compressing files used by another process, the function posted below will default to **[`[FileShare] 'ReadWrite, Delete'`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileshare?view=net-6.0)** when opening a [`FileStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.open?view=net-7.0).

---

To get around this issue there are two workarounds:

- The easy workaround is to use the [`ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.createfromdirectory?view=net-6.0#system-io-compression-zipfile-createfromdirectory(system-string-system-string)). There are 3 limitations while using this static method:

  1. The source **must be a directory**, a single file cannot be compressed.
  2. All files (recursively) on the source folder **will be compressed**, we can't pick / filter files to compress.
  3. It's not possible to **Update** the entries of an existing Zip Archive.

Worth noting, if you need to use the [`ZipFile` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile?view=net-6.0) in Windows PowerShell (.NET Framework) there must be a reference to `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`. See inline comments.

```bash
# Only needed if using Windows PowerShell (.NET Framework):
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

[IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourceDirectory, $destinationArchive)
```

- The code it yourself workaround, would be using a function which does all the manual process for creating the [`ZipArchive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=net-6.0) and the corresponding [`ZipEntries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive.createentry?view=net-6.0#system-io-compression-ziparchive-createentry(system-string-system-io-compression-compressionlevel)).

This function should be able to handle compression same as `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory` Method but also allow filtering files and folders to compress while keeping the **file / folder structure untouched**.

**Documentation as well as usage example can be found [here](https://github.com/santisq/PSCompression/blob/main/docs/Compress-ZipArchive.md).**

```bash
using namespace System.IO
using namespace System.IO.Compression
using namespace System.Collections.Generic

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression

function Compress-ZipArchive {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'Path')]
    [Alias('zip', 'ziparchive')]
    param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'PathWithUpdate', Mandatory, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'PathWithForce', Mandatory, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Path', Mandatory, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string[]] $Path,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'LiteralPathWithUpdate', Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'LiteralPathWithForce', Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'LiteralPath', Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [Alias('PSPath')]
        [string[]] $LiteralPath,

        [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory)]
        [string] $DestinationPath,

        [Parameter()]
        [CompressionLevel] $CompressionLevel = [CompressionLevel]::Optimal,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'PathWithUpdate', Mandatory)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'LiteralPathWithUpdate', Mandatory)]
        [switch] $Update,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'PathWithForce', Mandatory)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'LiteralPathWithForce', Mandatory)]
        [switch] $Force,

        [Parameter()]
        [switch] $PassThru
    )

    begin {
        $DestinationPath = $PSCmdlet.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($DestinationPath)
        if([Path]::GetExtension($DestinationPath) -ne '.zip') {
            $DestinationPath = $DestinationPath + '.zip'
        }

        if($Force.IsPresent) {
            $fsMode = [FileMode]::Create
        }
        elseif($Update.IsPresent) {
            $fsMode = [FileMode]::OpenOrCreate
        }
        else {
            $fsMode = [FileMode]::CreateNew
        }

        $ExpectingInput = $null
    }
    process {
        $isLiteral  = $false
        $targetPath = $Path

        if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('LiteralPath')) {
            $isLiteral  = $true
            $targetPath = $LiteralPath
        }

        if(-not $ExpectingInput) {
            try {
                $destfs = [File]::Open($DestinationPath, $fsMode)
                $zip    = [ZipArchive]::new($destfs, [ZipArchiveMode]::Update)
                $ExpectingInput = $true
            }
            catch {
                $zip, $destfs | ForEach-Object Dispose
                $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
            }
        }

        $queue = [Queue[FileSystemInfo]]::new()

        foreach($item in $ExecutionContext.InvokeProvider.Item.Get($targetPath, $true, $isLiteral)) {
            $queue.Enqueue($item)

            $here = $item.Parent.FullName
            if($item -is [FileInfo]) {
                $here = $item.Directory.FullName
            }

            while($queue.Count) {
                try {
                    $current = $queue.Dequeue()
                    if($current -is [DirectoryInfo]) {
                        $current = $current.EnumerateFileSystemInfos()
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    $PSCmdlet.WriteError($_)
                    continue
                }

                foreach($item in $current) {
                    try {
                        if($item.FullName -eq $DestinationPath) {
                            continue
                        }

                        $relative = $item.FullName.Substring($here.Length + 1)
                        $entry    = $zip.GetEntry($relative)

                        if($item -is [DirectoryInfo]) {
                            $queue.Enqueue($item)
                            if(-not $entry) {
                                $entry = $zip.CreateEntry($relative + '\', $CompressionLevel)
                            }
                            continue
                        }

                        if(-not $entry) {
                            $entry = $zip.CreateEntry($relative, $CompressionLevel)
                        }

                        $sourcefs = $item.Open([FileMode]::Open, [FileAccess]::Read, [FileShare] 'ReadWrite, Delete')
                        $entryfs  = $entry.Open()
                        $sourcefs.CopyTo($entryfs)
                    }
                    catch {
                        $PSCmdlet.WriteError($_)
                    }
                    finally {
                        $entryfs, $sourcefs | ForEach-Object Dispose
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    end {
        $zip, $destfs | ForEach-Object Dispose

        if($PassThru.IsPresent) {
            $DestinationPath -as [FileInfo]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: MS just updated their code (in beta currenlty) to provide an x64 implementaiton which no longer has the 2GB limit: https://github.com/PowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive/issues/19

Comment: @JohnLBevan that's good to know it was about time already. If you want you can edit my answer adding your comment to it.